# Why Raspbian jessie version 8 won't allow communication through GPIO serial pins?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, gpio, rpi.gpio, serial

I am running Raspbian Jessie 8 on Raspberry 3 and I followed the answer to the question [Why my program won't communicate through ttyAMA0 on Raspbian(jessie)?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/47671/why-my-program-wont-communicate-through-ttyama0-on-raspbian-jessie) But I still can't get my program to connect through serial GPIO pins.

I ran **gpio readall** command on the terminal and it said that PINS 15 and 16 (RX and TX) for serial is set to ALT5, but it needs to be ALT0. So, I ran the following command on the terminal.

`gpio mode 15 ALT0; gpio mode 16 ALT0;`

It changes the state of pins settings. However, my program keeps complaining that it can't connect to the serial port. I also noticed that once I reboot my PI, RX and TX pins changes back to ALT5. Am I missing something? or Any hints or clues will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make serial work on the Raspberry Pi3 , Pi3B+, PiZeroW](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45570/how-do-i-make-serial-work-on-the-raspberry-pi3-pi3b-pizerow)

Answer (score 2):

The Pi hardware has a full-UART and a mini-UART internal peripheral which supply serial services.

If GPIO 14/15 are in mode ALT0 the full-UART is connected to pins 8/10 (serial TXD/RXD).  If GPIO 14/15 are in mode ALT5 the mini-UART is connected to pins 8/10.

The full-UART is reserved for Bluetooth use in the Raspberry Pi3.  Therefore on the Pi3 you must use the mini-UART, i.e. you must set GPIO 14/15 to mode ALT5.

Refer to the port as /dev/serial0 when using pins 8/10 as a serial link.

Comment: Only for interesting: if I never need Bluetooth, can I then set to mode ALT0 and use the full-UART on pins 8/10?

Comment: @Ingo I believe so, I think you have to disable bluetooth though. See the end of milliways [answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45570/how-do-i-make-serial-work-on-the-raspberry-pi3-pi3b-pizerow)